# cocos2d fruit ninja parabola math

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

i am making a game similar to fruit ninja. birds flying down the water and then up (just like fruits up side down)

but some of the birds fly too far and the others too near. 
can someone check my code? vy should quite close to each other.(vx is not a problem)

```
static float tuna = 10.0f;
-(void) reset
{

    float vy = 0.0f;
    float vx = 0.0f;
    int sign = 1;
    if (CCRANDOM_0_1() >= 0.5) {
        sign = -1;
    }

    float hurry = 0.0f;
    if (CCRANDOM_0_1() <= 0.1) {
        hurry = 1.0f;
    }

    switch (birdType) {
        case BirdType1:
            vx = 1.0f * sign + (CCRANDOM_0_1() - 0.5f) * 0.08f;
            vy = -6.5f;
            break;
        case BirdType2:
            vx = 1.5f * sign + (CCRANDOM_0_1() - 0.5f) * 0.08f;
            vy = -6.2f + (CCRANDOM_0_1() - 0.5f) * 0.1f;
            break;
        case BirdType3:
            vx = 1.0f * sign + (CCRANDOM_0_1() - 0.5f) * 0.1f;
            vy = -5.8f - hurry;
            break;
        default:
            [NSException exceptionWithName:@"BirdMoveComponent exception" reason:@"unhandled bird type" userInfo:nil];
            break;
    }
    velocity = CGPointMake(vx * 5, vy * 5);


    if ((int)([[GameManager sharedManager] score] / 100) >= prevLevel) {
        if (tuna <= 12.0f) {
            tuna += 0.01f;
        }
        prevLevel = (int)[[GameManager sharedManager] score] / 100;
    }



}


-(void) update:(ccTime) delta
{

    if (self.parent.visible) {

        NSAssert([self.parent isKindOfClass:[BirdEntity class]], @"node is not an entity");
        BirdEntity* bird = (BirdEntity*) self.parent;

        bird.position = ccpAdd(bird.position, ccpMult(velocity, delta * tuna));

        velocity = ccpAdd(velocity, ccpMult(acceleration, delta * tuna));
        acceleration = ccp(0, 0.3f);

        float birdHeight = CGRectGetHeight([bird boundingBox]);

        //20 is the bottom trap
        if (bird.position.y <= (birdHeight / 2) + 20) {
            [bird dieAccidently];
        }

        if (CGRectIntersectsRect([GameScene screenRect], [bird boundingBox]) == NO)
        {
            bird.visible = NO;

            [bird stopAllActions];
            [bird unscheduleAllSelectors];
            [bird unscheduleUpdate];

            [self reset];
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Fruit Ninja with birds... sounds like a bloodbath!

Comment: yeah, that's the effects i want. still working on it. search "Fishes vs Birds" in 1 month (including apple approval time)^_^

Comment: I will watch out for it - please send me a link when you have approval! N

Answer (score 2):

thoght your question not programmatical but physical (mechanical).

position of object can be calculated from the system of equation:

```
x = Vx * t + x0
y = (-g*t*t)/2 + Vy * t + y0
```

, where g - Gravitational acceleration, V - initial speed, Vx and Vy - its projections on axes X and Y, respectively.

Question is what's the highest point, i.e. we need to found MAX(y(t)). 
derivative: `y'(t) = -g*t + Vy.`

```
y'(t) should equals zero, -g*t +  Vy  = 0;  t = Vy/g; MAX(y) = y(Vy/g) = Vy*Vy/2g. 

MAX(y) = Vy*Vy/2g + y0 // ballistic trajectory
MIN(y) = y0 - Vy*Vy/2g // your case
```

End you should calculate velocity accroding to this, if you want your bird Y to be in certain range.

Addition:

> btw is there a sample cocos2d code for
>   parabola?

Here is my working code.

```
    - (void) update: (ccTime)dt
    {
        t += dt*20;
        ...
        [self getVertices];
    }

    - (void) getVertices
    {
       //for every index: {
        ...
        //getting initial position (x0, y0)
        ...
vertices[index] = ccpAdd(vertices[index], ccpMult(velocity[index/3], t * screenFactor)); //+velocity*t
vertices[index] = ccpAdd(vertices[index], ccpMult(gravity, (t*t/2) * screenFactor));  //+acceleration*t^2 /2
      //}
    }
```

1) As you can see, there's no need to calculate Velocity every time: use initial speed.
2) Vertices is CGPoint array of current Sprite positions.
3) t (current time), vertices, gravity, velocity  are instance variables of common class.

Comment: i used a CGPoint to encapsulate velocity, same as acceleration. the acceleration is positive since the birds is underwater(like fruit ninja upside down), by the way, the origin for cocos2d is bottom-left corner

Comment: I did understood, but it's only a detail; OK, corrected formula is MIN(Y) = y0 - Vy*Vy/2g

Comment: i modified the code. multiply velocity by 3. just confused by the delta.

Comment: btw is there a sample cocos2d code for parabola? im not familiar with the measurement.

Comment: and is my way of level up correct? (delta * tuna, i increase tuna every 100 score) i didn't notice the speedup

Comment: well, what i really want is the concrete figures. (e.g.  vy = -6.2f + (CCRANDOM_0_1() - 0.5f) * 0.1f, this is too slow, 5x!) really  hard to mimic movement of fruitninja

Comment: actually updating velocity and position vs updating position only are the same. but i still can't handle the delta. why do you use 20 * delta? can you convert it into actual speed (mm/s not pixels/frame)? that's should be easier.

Comment: t = 1 is the same as 20 sec left in my case... OK, i realized my own code bug ))) thank you. You can calculate pixel size from device dimensions: iPad has approx pixel side of 0.192~0.194 mm (measured by ruler just now). Consider this, you can convert pixels/s to mm/s: 100 pixels/s ~ 19 mm/s

Comment: done now, i just tried some numbers and pick the one that works best. i believe it's quite a standard to calculate speed in my way. not a good approach to directly change positions^_^

Comment: same problem come up again. some times the birds even just show half of their body, then fly away. (some times no birds show up at all for 3-4 sec)......

Comment: I cant solve your problem for you (I have two projects by now, where I act as both programmer and project manager), I just have no time. Use engineer approach. Solve your problem in two steps: 1) Make a good feasible mathematical model. I prefer A4 piece of paper and pencil. Write down the constraints (Where birds have to start, how low should they plane, and so on). Write down characteristic equations. Make a sketch for clarity. Eventually you would get a specification that meet all constraints. 2) If your specification good enough, write it in Objective-C/Cocos2d.

Comment: im still unclear about (ccTime) delta, does it have anything to do with how far it can go, or just affect the time(speed)? good luck for you project.

Comment: "delta" is just T(current "update" call) - T(previous "update" call). In other words, delta = (1/frames_per_second), cause frames are updated with the "update" call