# cocos2d check collision

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, collision

I want to check collision of birds and fishes.

I have a `BirdCache` which contains

```
-(void) isBirdCollidingWithRect:(CGRect) rect
```

which check every visible bird in the cache

```
-(void) update:(ccTime) delta
```

which call `isFishCollidingWithRect` to test every bird, if `YES`, `bird.visible = NO`

and a `FishCache` (similar to `BirdCache`)

but the result is the fish never die when they collide. (I do set `visible = NO` in both update

I think the problem is racing condition when `bird.visible = NO` first, then fish will not be colliding with the bird. then I tried to `schedule:selector(delayedInvisible) interval: 1.0 / 10.0f`, but still failed.

Is there any common approach to this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this work like that:

- for every living bird you check if it
  collides with any fish, and if it
  does, you kill the bird
- for every living fish you check if it collides with any bird, and if it
  does, you kill the fish

So if bird collides with fish only bird is killed.

You have to kill both colliding objects in each method, or add field to birds and fishes that says (this animal should be killed next frame), and set this on collision, not the visible field directly.

Comment: add field to birds and fishes that says (this animal should be killed next frame), and set this on collision, not the visible field directly.      yeah, i do have a delayedInvisible method that will be called 1/10 second later. inside delayedInvisible I unschedule:_cmd first and then set invisible

Comment: I would do without multithreading. Do you have a method that loops throught all the fishes and birds in each frame?

Comment: your solution worked!!!i just let the [fish gotHit] before returning true. but i still wanna know why my original way didn't work. it's single thread. and yes, in the isFish/BirdCollidingWithRect, i checked all the fishes/birds

Comment: by the way, the only problem left(maybe) is the movement of birds. could you check my question here?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295028/cocos2d-fruit-ninja-parabola-math

Comment: I don't know objective c, nor cocoa, but I suspect that you first checked the collisions for birds, and when collision occured you set that bird as killed, but you've left the colliding fish alive. Then you checked collisions of each fish with each alive bird, and our fish didn't collided with any, because the bird colliding with the fish was already killed.